# relationships between tables in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have one table with 6 columns. I have another 6 tables with two columns.Each of these 6 tables have id column and value column.These 6 tables are dropdowns in my app, and I want now each value from dropdown e.g from one table of these 6 to be referenced somehow with first table which has 6 columns that supposed to be ID foreach of these 6 columns ID.I trying with hours but I cant reference these tables.E.g when user pick some value from dropdown, how first table with six columns to know what value is selected from another table.Could anyone help me here?Thanks

Comment: Maybe if you posted your code we could help debug it.   We're not going to write an entire solution for you from scratch.

Comment: @TabAlleman i dont want a solution i need help in part of sql, how main table with 6 columns would be referenced with rest 6 tables, i need relationshipsh here...

Comment: We can't see your screen, have no idea what your current table structures are, and no knowledge of your project. How do you expect anybody to offer much advice here?

Comment: *"I have 6 boxes with a padlock in each one, and one box with 6 keys... which key opens each lock?"* How could I expect anyone to know? There is nowhere near enough information here. We can't describe your own schema for you. If you made it you should already know the relationships. If you didn't make it, you'll have to either ask the person who did, or guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

If I got you right (I hope so), you want to create one table containing foreign-key columns referencing to the Dropdown values. So, each row contains 6 dropdown values.

Is this what you're looking for?

```
--Data Tables
CREATE TABLE [DropDownTable1]
(
    [DropDownTable1Id] INT Identity(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [pk__dropdowntable1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([DropDownTable1Id] ASC)
);
CREATE TABLE [DropDownTable2]
(
    [DropDownTable2Id] INT Identity(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [pk__dropdowntable2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([DropDownTable2Id] ASC)
);
CREATE TABLE [DropDownTable3]
(
    [DropDownTable3Id] INT Identity(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [pk__dropdowntable3] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([DropDownTable3Id] ASC)
);
CREATE TABLE [DropDownTable4]
(
    [DropDownTable4Id] INT Identity(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [pk__dropdowntable4] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([DropDownTable4Id] ASC)
);
CREATE TABLE [DropDownTable5]
(
    [DropDownTable5Id] INT Identity(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [pk__dropdowntable5] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([DropDownTable5Id] ASC)
);
CREATE TABLE [DropDownTable6]
(
    [DropDownTable6Id] INT Identity(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [pk__dropdowntable6] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([DropDownTable6Id] ASC)
);

--Table with relations
CREATE TABLE [TbWithSixColumns]
(
    [TbWithSixColumnsId] INT Identity(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DropDownTable1Id] INT NOT NULL,
    [DropDownTable2Id] INT NOT NULL,
    [DropDownTable3Id] INT NOT NULL,
    [DropDownTable4Id] INT NOT NULL,
    [DropDownTable5Id] INT NOT NULL,
    [DropDownTable6Id] INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [pk__tbwithsixcolumns] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TbWithSixColumnsId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [fk__tbwithsixcolumns__dropdowntable1id] FOREIGN KEY([DropDownTable1Id]) REFERENCES [DropDownTable1]([DropDownTable1Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [fk__tbwithsixcolumns__dropdowntable2id] FOREIGN KEY([DropDownTable2Id]) REFERENCES [DropDownTable2]([DropDownTable2Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [fk__tbwithsixcolumns__dropdowntable3id] FOREIGN KEY([DropDownTable3Id]) REFERENCES [DropDownTable3]([DropDownTable3Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [fk__tbwithsixcolumns__dropdowntable4id] FOREIGN KEY([DropDownTable4Id]) REFERENCES [DropDownTable4]([DropDownTable4Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [fk__tbwithsixcolumns__dropdowntable5id] FOREIGN KEY([DropDownTable5Id]) REFERENCES [DropDownTable5]([DropDownTable5Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [fk__tbwithsixcolumns__dropdowntable6id] FOREIGN KEY([DropDownTable6Id]) REFERENCES [DropDownTable6]([DropDownTable6Id])
);

--Populate Test-Data
INSERT INTO [DropDownTable1] ([Name]) VALUES ('Dropdownentry 1.1')
INSERT INTO [DropDownTable2] ([Name]) VALUES ('Dropdownentry 2.1')
INSERT INTO [DropDownTable3] ([Name]) VALUES ('Dropdownentry 3.1')
INSERT INTO [DropDownTable4] ([Name]) VALUES ('Dropdownentry 4.1')
INSERT INTO [DropDownTable5] ([Name]) VALUES ('Dropdownentry 5.1')
INSERT INTO [DropDownTable6] ([Name]) VALUES ('Dropdownentry 6.1')
INSERT INTO [TbWithSixColumns] ([DropDownTable1Id],[DropDownTable2Id],[DropDownTable3Id],[DropDownTable4Id],[DropDownTable5Id],[DropDownTable6Id]) VALUES (1,1,1,1,1,1);

--Query the dropdown data
SELECT  t1.Name, t2.Name, t3.Name, t4.Name, t5.Name, t6.Name 
FROM [TbWithSixColumns] relationTb
INNER JOIN [DropDownTable1] t1 ON relationTb.DropDownTable1Id = t1.DropDownTable1Id
INNER JOIN [DropDownTable2] t2 ON relationTb.DropDownTable2Id = t2.DropDownTable2Id
INNER JOIN [DropDownTable3] t3 ON relationTb.DropDownTable3Id = t3.DropDownTable3Id
INNER JOIN [DropDownTable4] t4 ON relationTb.DropDownTable4Id = t4.DropDownTable4Id
INNER JOIN [DropDownTable5] t5 ON relationTb.DropDownTable5Id = t5.DropDownTable5Id
INNER JOIN [DropDownTable6] t6 ON relationTb.DropDownTable6Id = t6.DropDownTable6Id
```

Please notice:
When asking questions, be as specific as you can and provide as much details as possible (We really appreciate Code Snippets, Data-Models and Images that help to describe your problem). The more details you provide, the more we are able to fully understand where you got stuck. Further, it is much easier for us, if we don't have to build a whole solution from scratch. (And, since developers are lazy, you also increase the probability that someone answers ;)

I hope I could help you.